# Changing the random product selection mechanism in Mangento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, random

Our Magento installation has a home page block which displays a random selection of products from a given category. It works, but it's **really** slow. I tracked the culprit down to the following function:

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_productCollection))
    {
        $categoryID = $this->getCategoryId();
        if($categoryID)
        {
            $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
            $category->load($categoryID);
            $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
        }
        else
        {
            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        }
        Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);

        if ($this->getIsRandom())
        {
            $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()'); // REALLY slow, approx 4000ms at 25k products
        }

        $collection->addStoreFilter();
        $productCount = $this->getProductCount() ? $this->getProductCount() : 8;
        $collection->setPage(1, $productCount)
            ->load();

        $this->_productCollection = $collection;
    }
    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

Specifically, it is the `$collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');` statement that is **extremely** slow, adding around 4000ms to our time to first byte at our current product count of ~25k. Simply disabling randomness shaves about 3700ms off our page load time.

I would like to perform the randomization at application level, rather than use the notoriously slow MySQL `ORDER BY RAND()` method. I tried applying the method described in: [Randomise & limit Category thumbs on homepage magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440874/randomise-limit-category-thumbs-on-homepage-magento), specifically changing:

```
$collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
```

into this (and varying permutations thereof):

```
$collection->getSelect()->addIdFilter(array_rand(array_flip($category->getAllChildren(true)),5));
```

The effect is that now the block is not shown at all in the front end. I would appreciate any advice on how to implement the solution linked above, or any other efficient way to randomize the *$collection* variable referenced above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution to the problem above; this uses application, rather than database-level randomization and does yield significant improvements on Magento's time-to-first-byte.

```
function _getProductCollection()
{

    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $categoryID = $this->getCategoryId();
        if ($categoryID) {
            $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
            $category->load($categoryID);
            $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
        } else {
            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        }

        Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);

        $maxsize = $collection->getSize();
        $randArray = array();
        while (count($randArray) <= 50) {
            $randArray[] = rand(1, $maxsize);
        }

        if ($this->getIsRandom()) {
            $collection->getSelect()->where('product_id IN (?)',$randArray)->order('RAND()');
        }

        $collection->addStoreFilter();
        $productCount = $this->getProductCount() ? $this->getProductCount() : 8;
        $collection->setPage(1, $productCount)->load();

        $this->_productCollection = $collection;
    }
    return $this->_productCollection;

}
```